# Accessing GPS data on LG VX8360 phone

Tags: javascript, mobile, geolocation, gps

I am trying to design a web page that provides content depending on the user's location. I made a simple page that tries to access the navigator.geolocation object and report whether it exists, and if it does, the latitude and longitude reported by the browser. I tested it on my home computer, which is running Firefox, and it worked fine.

I then tested it on my LG VX8360 cell phone and it didn't work. After some experimentation, I found out that navigator.geolocation doesn't seem to exist in my mobile browser. My phone is not at all the most sophisticated, but it does have GPS capability and I made sure it was enabled.

I tried looking on Google to find anything about accessing the GPS data, but I couldn't find any way of doing it that doesn't involve paying for the VZ Navigator app. Does anyone know of any way? I would ideally like some way of making a web page that can access it.

Comment: You may have to think about how you can get access to it from a web page. A web page can just go scrawling your phone for its GPS data unless it is readily made available.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do. I am asking how, if at all possible, can I determine the user's location from a web page? It seems reasonable that there should be some way of doing it, at least on phones with GPS. However, I tried doing it on my phone with GPS and I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LG VX8360 supports the Flash Lite player.

Flash Lite has a [Geolocation class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashlite/dev/4/WSa2ec538c80d45833-1064af75123373fed78-8000.html) that can hook into the Java J2ME JSR-179 geolocation support that the LG VX8360 also supports.

It is possible to write a Flash Lite compatible component and host it on your web page that Flash Lite on the LG can run.

Comment: I was really hoping someone would answer this one.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know anything about Flash development, but I may give this a try.

Comment: One approach if you don't want to develop the whole thing in Flash is getting the geolocation data using the Flash component and passing it to the code in your web page where you're more comfortable working with it. Not done that myself, however there'll be plenty of documentation out there (as well as folks here monitoring the [Flash] tag willing to answer questions!).

Comment: I really know nothing about Flash programming. It may take me a long time to learn enough to know how to try your answer. I will still give you the bounty since you provided the only answer and it looks plausible to me.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have to have the newest mobile phone to use GPS and Geolocation API. Almost every mobile browser (without proxy server) can be used to read position from buidin GPS. If You have Java and GPS in Your phone – You can use mobile-gps-web-gate – see at http://code.google.com/p/mobile-gps-web-gate/